# I can't download the zip archive from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a React client and a Node server. When I send a POST request to the server, server should zip the folder and download it to the client. This cannot be done. A broken archive is downloaded to the client.
Moreover, the archive on the server is created correctly.

Below code example
React client

```
function test() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/download", {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(data => {
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(data)
      let anchor = document.createElement('a')
      anchor.href = url
      anchor.download = 'ex_new.zip'
      document.body.appendChild(anchor)
      anchor.style = 'display: none'
      anchor.click()
      anchor.remove()

      URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
      document.removeChild(anchor)
    })
}

function App() {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => test()}>Test</button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Node server

```
const archiver = require("archiver")
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require('path')


const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.post("/download", (req, res) => {

    const archive = archiver('zip')
    archive.directory('output')
    archive.finalize()
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/ex.zip')
    archive.pipe(output)
    return res.download('/home/user/Js', 'ex.zip')
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server start"))
```

[Screenshot old error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TNaK.png)

[Screenshot new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNPrb.png)

[Screenshot Chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kken.png)

[Networks Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnXAQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that your node server is not sending the zip file correctly. You are using `archiver` to make a zip file and write it to a stream, but you are not checking if the stream is done before you send the response. This could make the zip file broken or incomplete. You can fix this by either waiting for the stream to finish with the `archive.finalize` method, or sending the file right away with the `res.attachment` method.

For example:

```
app.post("/download", (req, res) => {
  const archive = archiver("zip");
  archive.directory("output");
  archive.finalize();
  res.attachment("ex.zip");
  archive.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: I did as you said, but now the archive is not downloaded even broken, an error is generated: ERROR NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: I used return, now I checked again, still the same error. Plus there is a Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/download. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Comment: It didn’t work (Still the same error. I copied my code and pasted it into the project again. It may depend on browser or OS? Added screenshot

Comment: Yes, that's right. With the old code, another error occurred and a broken archive was downloaded, a screenshot was added

Comment: The old error is occurred by `document.removeChild(anchor)`, please remove this line. and please try on chrome.

Comment: Tried in Chrome. An error has occurred. Added a screenshot.

Comment: Please show me network tab and error in chrome dev tools

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254513/chatting-with-sudoers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't wait for the file to be created before writing it to the response, which causes the content length specified in the response not to match the actual length of the zip file (and the file content would be incomplete or empty).

Try like this:

```
app.post("/download", (req, res) => {

    const archive = archiver('zip')
    archive.directory('output')
    archive.finalize()
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/ex.zip')
    archive.pipe(output)
    output.on('finish', () => res.download('/home/user/Js', 'ex.zip'))
})
```